# How to call function after every 15 seconds in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a function which I want to call after every 15 seconds , I am using react functional hooks could someone please help me how to resolve this issue .

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
 useEffect(()=>{sendData()},[])

 const sendData = ()=> {
   console.log('Sending data')
 }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can create a code sandbox and post the link here. and this kind of problem has got answers in StackOverflow already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
 useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      sendData();
    }, 15000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

 const sendData = ()=> {
   console.log('Sending data')
 }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```